# What does Bismika Allahuma mean?

Tags: arabic-translation

Bismillahir Rahman-ir-Rahim means In the name of Allah the most loving and kind or the most gracious and merciful. What does Bismika Allahuma mean?

Comment: It means "In Your Name O Allah".

Answer (score 1):

**Bismika Allahumma** means **"O Allah, with Your Name"**

Here's some examples with some supplications mentioned:

**Allahumma bismika** amutu wa ahya
**O Allah, with Your name** I die and live

Whenever the Prophet (S.a.W) lay down for sleep at night, he would place his (right) hand under his (right) cheek and supplicate: **"Bismika Allahumma** amutu wa ahya [**O Allah, with Your Name** will I die and live (wake up)]." Sahih al Bukhari